# Does a test version of firebase allow you things like seeing the database fields

Tags: firebase

I need to add fields to my database.  I go to firebase console and click my project.  I click firestore, but instead of seeing anything about my database, I just see a video on how to get started.  I am using the free version.  Do I have to use the pay version to manipulate the database.  I can save data to the database and my app pulls data.  But I can't seems to see any of the screens on the console that the help section says I should see?  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to pay anything to use Firebase database products.  There is a [free tier with limits](https://firebase.google.com/pricing).  Make sure you are looking at the correct database and project.  Firebase has two different databases, so maybe you are looking at the wrong one.

If you're having problems with errors in the Firebase console, you should reach out to [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) and explain the problem. Stack Overflow likely won't be able to help you.

Comment: If I uninstall my app from my device, rewrite the table structure in my createEmployeeTable sql function and rebuild my project, will the new table be created on firebase?

Comment: If you have a new question, please post it separately.  I suggest actually trying to do the thing you want to do first, then post if you have problems with that.  Note that neither Firebase database has anything called a "table".